# Looking for data: Fee rate Per Transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, transaction-fees

I'm looking for websites (dashboards, charts, etc.) and/or datasets which show,

- average daily transaction fees (sat/vB)
- average/min/max fees of each block (sat/vB)

Also, what would be the steps to pull and compile this data myself from a Bitcoin Core Full Node?

Cheers

Comment: The first half of your question would be considered off-topic here (asking for a product/service recommendation/review), but the second half of it would be on-topic (asking how to do it yourself). You may consider editing the question to be entirely on topic, that may elicit better answers.

Comment: @chytrik: No, the asker here is trying to solve a problem "How can I get XY data?".  That's not a service recommendation. It would be a recommendation/review if the question were "What's the best way to get XY?". I agree it's subtle, but someone trying to figure out how to solve a problem is on-topic here.

Comment: @Murch hmm I don't really disagree with you there, but as written it certainly may illicit answers that read "this website/API has the data you need", which don't tend to age well. It is indeed subtle though, I don't mean to discourage Qs in any case.

Comment: My litmus test is whether a question prompts answers to select one out of many options or requests an evaluation or comparison of service offerings. It's not clear cut because it's all part of the spectrum "How can I achieve something?" ⇔ "Which service is your favorite?".

Answer (score 1):

You can for example find the "average feerate distribution in blocks per day" here: https://transactionfee.info/charts/fees-package-feerates/

I'm not aware of a direct source for "average/min/max fees of each block (sat/vB)" for free (I checked transactionfee.info, statoshi.info, and txstats.com). Coinmetrics has them as "pro metrics" but not in the free community version.

Some block explorers (e.g. blockchair.com) allow you to search transactions per block. You could use that to script retrieval of the transaction with the smallest feerate and the transaction with the highest feerate from each block (don't forget to exclude the coinbase transaction, and note that CPFP could skew your perception of the lower bound). You can estimate the average feerate via dividing the total fees of a block by its total weight.

You could extract all of that information from the blockchain directly, but that is a non-trivial amount of work.